# Install Ubuntu/Linux on new Kaby Lake processor

Tags: system-installation

I'm buying a new laptop and refuse to use Win 10.  Being disabled, I’m having a hard time getting/searching for an answer to what I hope is a fairly straight forward question:

Can I install Ubuntu or any Linux distribution on the new Intel Kaby Lake processors?

I’m not sure what specific info you’ll need, so I’m including all the major specs:
Sager P650HS-G / HM175 chipset / 7820HK processor / 64 GB RAM - Kingston Hyper X CL14 2400MHz / nVidia 1070 w/ G-Sync / Samsung 960 Pro NVMe M.2 for the OS / Duel Samsung 850 EVO SSD in RAID / Bigfoot Wireless-N1535 M.2

Hopefully all this will work with Ubuntu.  If any components listed need something special installed to work, please help direct me to what else I’ll need to do.

Thank you everyone for your help with this question!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=pstate-cpufreq-kbl&num=1, it will work, but there are some performance bugs, and you may need the latest kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/.  Also, I would install Ubuntu 16.10 and update it to 17.04 as soon as it comes out.

Comment: I might even start with 17.04, if willing to be a tester and the possibility that it may break. Or set up two / (root) one 16.10 and the other 17.04. You are going to need newest kernel & drivers. Another new Sager: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350059

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, for that specs Linux Ubuntu will work surely. I just recently built Kaby Lake processor and Sky Lake motherboard. I installed Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. There was no OS pre-installed on my system. I just needed to upgrade my Sky Lake motherboard to Kaby Lake BIOS system, and then everything worked fine.

My PC specs:

```
CPU: Intel Kaby Lake Pentium G4560 3.5GHz 3MB Cache LGA 1151
Motherboard: Asrock H110M-DVS R3.0 Intel H110 2133MHz DDR4
RAM: Team Elite Plus 8GB DDR4 2133MHz
HDD: Toshiba 1TB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache 3,5" SATA III DISK
```

That's all, man. Stick your USB and install Ubuntu, voila. About some problems on Linux Ubuntu, yes I have some problems on my PC, like Chromium and Google Chrome browsers don't open, but still I like Ubuntu. I like dealing with problems and learning the Linux on the go. By the way, I suggest to install Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not the latter versions, because LTS is Long term support. In the beginning LTS will be good for you.

PS: We, as an Ubuntu community gladly welcome you new guys to our friendly community. Good luck.